# Structs em C podem ter construtores?

Tags: c, struct

Tenho a seguinte estrutura dentro de um programa:

```
 struct STR00034ST{

     char C_O010XC14B, C_O020XC14B;
     short S_0010XI15C;
     float F_0010XI1D;

     STR00034ST (char _C_O010XC14B, char _C_O020XC14B,  short _S_0010XI15C, float _F_0010XI1D){

        C_O010XC14B=_C_O010XC14B;
        C_O020XC14B=_C_O020XC14B;
        S_0010XI15C=_S_0010XI15C; 
        F_0010XI1D=_F_0010XI1D;
    }
};
```

Porém sempre que compilo retorna o seguinte erro: 'error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'STR00034ST''

Andei pesquisando e percebi que só achava exemplos de uso de construtores em struct dentro da linguagem C++ e não em C. Portanto, é impossível usar construtores dentro de uma struct em C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não é possível utilizar construtores em C, portanto você teria que criar uma funcão auxiliar que cria e inicializa structs.
Em C99 existe também uma técninca chamada *Compound Literal*, que constroi uma estrutura *in-place*. A sintaxe (em inglês) seria:

`( type ) {  initializer-list }` ,

por exemplo,

`struct foo {int a; char b[2];} structure;`.

Comment: Só seu exemplo de inicialização que não inicializa nada. O resto parece-me correto